# php DomXPath - how to strip html tags and its contents from nodeValue?

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

In this code

```
<root>
    <main>
        <cont>
            <p>hello<a>world</a></p>
            <p>hello</p>
            <p>hello<a>world</a></p>
        </cont>
    </main>
</root>
```

I just need to get only the text inside `<cont>` tag. without getting `<a>` tag and `its contents`

so, the results will be `hello hello hello` without `world`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the text nodes that are a direct descendant of each `<p>` tag:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXml($xmlData);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//cont/p/text()') as $text) {
    echo $text->textContent, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `simplexml_load_string()` or `simplexml_load_file()` should be enough:

```
$xml_string = '<root> <main> <cont> <p>hello<a>world</a></p> <p>hello</p> <p>hello<a>world</a></p> </cont> </main></root>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
$p = $xml->main->cont->p;
foreach($p as $value) {
    $parapgraphs[] = (string) $value;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($parapgraphs);
```

Should show something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => hello
    [2] => hello
)
```

Comment: The problem is that `<a>` is *inside* `<p>`.